# Cannot display value on web page by using Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to display some values which is queried out from mysql in the method within views.py on the web page, but I cannot see that on the web page. see my method in views.py:

```
def update_delete_customer(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("TODO")

    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
        if id is None:
            print("id is None")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('AddressTableMaintain/')
        print("----------------")
        print(id)
        customerList = Customer.objects.raw("select * from customers where customer_id = %s", [int(id)])
        customer = list(customerList)[0]
        print(customer)
        form.customerId = customer.customerId
        form.first_name = customer.first_name
        form.last_name = customer.last_name
        print(customer.customerId)
        print(customer.first_name)
        print(customer.last_name)
        return render(request, 'EditCustomer.html', {'form': form})
    return HttpResponseRedirect('AddressTableMaintain/')
```

I can see the output customer id, first name, last name that are generated by the print function in the console.
Below is the contents of my EditCustomer.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Remove or Update customer {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<form action="{% url 'RU_customer_post' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table width="50%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Customer ID</td>
        <td>
            {{ form.customer_id }}

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>
            {{ form.first_name }}

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>
            {{ form.last_name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value = "OK" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My expected result is the value should be bound to web page and displayed, but the actual effect is like below:

[image]

So, can someone tell me why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
    form = CustomerForm()
    if id is None:
        print("id is None")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('AddressTableMaintain/')
    print("----------------")
    print(id)
    customerList = Customer.objects.raw("select * from customers where customer_id = %s", [int(id)])
    customer = list(customerList)[0]
```

with:

```
    if id is None:
        print("id is None")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('AddressTableMaintain/')
    print("----------------")
    print(id)
    customerList = Customer.objects.raw("select * from customers where customer_id = %s", [int(id)])
    form = CustomerForm(list(customerList)[0])
```

Possibly related: Why are you using raw SQL instead of the much simpler:

```
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=id)
```

which would return the one customer that you are looking for?

Comment: I got error message: Customer matching query does not exist. when I search it like this: customer2 = Customer.objects.get(pk=1)

Comment: Are you sure id 1 exists? Can you post the Customer model class?